# popupextendercontrol causes postback in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-3.5

I've tried putting an asp button (with use submit equals false) or an asp textbox that should open the popup pnel (which I've defined), but the popupextender causes a postback and displays all of the current page content (instead of iring the page method I defined).

It's nearly 5 hours of debugging, opening new projects (to try and reproduct the case in other project) and so on.
Thanks in advance...

This is the body of the page that handles the user control:

```
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>    
       <ucpop:popup ID="gv" runat="server" />
      </div>
   </form>
```

This is the usercontrol:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upExample">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvCars"
            OnDataBinding="gvCars_DataBinding"
            OnRowCommand="gvCars_RowCommand"
            >            
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>                        
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ibPopup" ImageUrl="~/Resources/Perspective-Button-Go-icon.png" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                    <ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="pce" runat="server" TargetControlID="ibPopup" DynamicControlID="pToUpdate"
                        PopupControlID="pToExtend" DynamicContextKey='<%#Eval("id") %>' DynamicServiceMethod="GetDynamicContent">
                    </ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender>
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pToExtend" BackColor="Red" style="display:none">Hello
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pToUpdate">
                    </asp:Panel>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>                        
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lidPopup" Text='<%=Eval("id") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>                        
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lNamePopup" Text='<%=Eval("Name") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>  
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>                        
                    <asp:ImageButton CommandName="p" runat="server" ID="ibNotPopUp" ImageUrl="~/Resources/Perspective-Button-Go-icon.png" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                                                
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is the Page web codebehind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
    public static string GetDynamicContent(string contextKey)
    {
        StringBuilder sTemp = new StringBuilder();

        sTemp.Append(string.Format("<div>Cool! I'm {0}</div>", contextKey));

        return sTemp.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is the UserControl codebehind:

```
         public partial class GridViewWithPopUpControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gvCars.DataBind();
        }     
    }

    protected void gvCars_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            string t = e.CommandName;
        }
    }

    protected void gvCars_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        gv.DataSource = CarList.CarCollection;
    }
}
```

It's pretty standard code... yet not working as expected. I think of upgrading the ajaxtoolkit, but other features in the web site system might be ruined, so I have to think it over.
Thanks again.

Comment: Could you post the code you are having issues with?

Comment: have you used an **UpdatePanel** to hold controls that you want to put into your **PopUp**

Comment: I did try to put the UpdatePanel inside the ItemTemplate that I require to show the popup, and the same issue happens... When I debug it, a postback is done (it gets into the Page_Load), and it doesn't fire the static web method... I thought of putting the web method inside another (empty) page, but it didn't help much either. Instead it renders all the page inside the popup control (making the content visible twice).

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, the Page method wasn't in the page but rather in the User Control. 
I did not write the User Control nor the page, I just needed to add functionality and found that problem - and fixed it...